# No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener exception in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, android-support-library

I downloaded yesterday Android Studio 2.1.3 (before I worked with 1.5) and now I have this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/support/v4/view/OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompatLollipop; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatLollipop'
```

that stops my app on setContentView in the MainActivity. 
How can I solve this?

Comment: the problem is not the code! because it works on other laptops

Comment: is your instant run enable?

Comment: Please check that every "com.android.support:xxx:..." on your grade file is 24.2.0

Comment: This link might help you..[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631655/appcompatactivity-is-not-working-properly)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had same issue. I tried to run my code on another system with latest downloaded version of Android SDK (API 24). `compileSdkVersion` of my code was 23. So, what I did is I opened `app.iml` file (located in app module) and found version of components installed and updated them in build.gradle(app module) file.

Like,

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

And also updated `compileSdkVersion` to 24, `buildToolsVersion`  to `24.0.1`, `targetSdkVersion` to `24`.
Now my code runs fine.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. That's classic case, you'll need just to update all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

i have also face this type of error after update android studio 2.1.2 to 2.1.3

try MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity to

MainActivity extends Activity

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: sorry,this is not answer but i can not add coment so i try this

Comment: Try to extends AppCompatActivity  to Activity

Comment: @RupalTri yes, the MainActivity already extends AppCompactActivity.  My project works on Android Studio 2.1.2 of my friend, so I think I need to fix something with this version

Comment: yaa i konw frd i am also trying

Comment: my problem was solved but not know how so i am finding

Answer (score 0):

It's should be the same problem as [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049107/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-setonapplywindowinsetslistener)

Try to only use the 24.2.0 version for all the "com.android.support:xxx:..." in your gradle file.

BTW, now, support v4 is split (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#24-2-0-v4-refactor). Try to use only what you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have also face this type of error after update android studio 2.1.2 to 2.1.3, so I change AppCompat version from 23.4.0 to 24.2.0. Hope it will work! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the support library versions to the latest solved my problem.

Snapshot of the constants defined in gradle.properties:

```
BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23.0.2
COMPILE_SDK_VERSION=23
TARGET_SDK_VERSION=23
DESIGN_SUPPORT_VERSION=24.2.0 //changed from 23.2.0
APPCOMPAT_VERSION=24.2.0 //changed from 23.2.0
ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=24.2.0 //changed from 23.2.0
```

Snapshot of the dependencies I added:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${project.APPCOMPAT_VERSION}"){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:${project.PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${project.PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${project.DESIGN_SUPPORT_VERSION}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${project.ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${project.PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${project.PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION}"
    /* google maps*/
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.5'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
    compile project(':volley')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the issue :

i also faced this this issue once, and i found that i was using invalid dependency in my gradle :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```

use this version of design or some other library, it solved my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

These are my configuration:
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

Dependency:
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'

I tried many things but finally it worked by updating Android SDK platform tools.
 
 
Steps:

1. Open SDK Manager
2. Android SDK -> SDK tools
3. Select Android SDK Platform - Tools (26.0.0) & Android SDK Tools (26.0.2)
4. After downloading clean & build your project.