# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener

Tags: android, oncreate, appcompatactivity

I upgraded my android studio to 2.1.3. And now I am getting following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/support/v4/view/OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompatLollipop; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatLollipop' appears in /data/data/com.restroshop.restroowner/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_7c318f8d2adb03d07a9def5d35a14e39204ecef2-classes.dex)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$LollipopViewCompatImpl.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(ViewCompat.java:1619)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(ViewCompat.java:2924)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:425)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.restroshop.restroowner.splash.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:65)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6033)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
```

in line `setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);`

My code snippet is

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen); // this line giving error
    }
```

I have no idea what exactly went wrong while upgrading.

Comment: Please check that every "com.android.support:xxx:..." on your grade file is 24.2.0

Comment: Thanks @Idemay. It worked for me.

Comment: Awesome, check https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#24-2-0-v4-refactor , the v4 library is now split.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**I upgraded my android studio to 2.1.3. And now I am getting following error**

I am also suffering with same issue. But I was resolved as the following way.

Reason of this exception is AppcompatActivity derived from the v7 library. so we should provide proper library based on your gradle and SDK.

1. should update the dependency Libraries also.
2. Right click on the project in the project structure -> select Open module    settings and select dependencies tab -> Library module-> then type which library you want add to the project. It shows the latest libraries based on your gradle updated version, then select latest one and remove the existing one.

For example In my project "appcompat-v7" version is 23.4.0 then I was changed to 24.2.0.

Answer (score 19):

I had this error coming due to multiple version of same library.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
```

The butterknife was adding the new version of the appcombat lib.
I checked it using

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies
```

The way gradle works it automatically updates the library to new library version, if available.
So I added the following code

```
compile('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1') {
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

It worked fine after that.

Comment: You bought back the coder in me... i was struggling from last two days..and the thing was `exclude module` this saved me...so a thumbs up to you bro...

Comment: I can understand. I was stuck myself on this problem. It is quite frustrating!