# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDrawable(Landroid/content/Context;I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-support-library

I updated Android Studio to 2.2 and my project won't build anymore. My Activity's super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) gives me an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDrawable(Landroid/content/Context;I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/x.y.z-1/base.apk:classes32.dex)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:720)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:147)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:27)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:50)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:29)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:199)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:181)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:521)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
                                                                     at zz.yyy.xxx.activities.AsdActivity.onCreate(AsdActivity.java:12)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I made a completely new Activity to see if it was my code that was causing the problem but it didn't help. Here's the activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AsdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_asd);
    }
}
```

And here's my build.gradle (app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
           minSdkVersion 21
           targetSdkVersion 24
           ...
        }

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            ...
            minifyEnabled false
        }

        release {
            ...
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile project(':ViewLib')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.5.jar')
    compile project(':GridHeaders')
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.16'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v0.9.3'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics:2.2.9'
    compile('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.11.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'org.apache:pdfbox-android:1.8.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
}
```

Before this error I got this: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049107/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-setonapplywindowinsetslistener)

And before that I had another similar error. Both were fixed by updating my support libraries. Now I got the newest (24.2.1) version of appcompatv7 and design libraries so I don't know how what I can do anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve this problem. Under my /libs folder I had an old android-support-v13.jar that got compiled with gradle. My app tried to use the ContextCompat class of this .jar and the class didn't have the static getDrawable(Context) method. Removing this .jar solved my problem.

Comment: I have same problem but android-support-v13.jar file no found in my lib folder plz help...

Comment: I check 'at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable' file it gives C:\Users\ajagtap\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7\25.3.0\appcompat-v7-25.3.0-sources.jar!\android\support\v7\widget\AppCompatDrawableManager.java path