# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDrawable(Landroid/content/Context;I)

Tags: android, socialize-sdk

Am Integrating Socialize SDK into my app.I also updated my Android Studio to 2.3.3. My Activity's super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) gives me an error. The same question has been raised here'[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDrawable(Landroid/content/Context;I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617770/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-getdrawablelandroid-content-conte)'. But that doesn't help me as I dont have any jar files under my libs folder.

```
--------- beginning of crash
    06-12 16:07:41.954 16968-16968/com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashriskitchen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                           Process: com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashriskitchen, PID: 16968
                                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDrawable(Landroid/content/Context;I)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable; in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashriskitchen-1/base.apk:classes8.dex)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:201)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:189)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:710)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:129)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:152)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV23.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV23.java:31)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplN.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplN.java:31)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:200)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:184)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:518)
                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:70)
                                                                                               at com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashriskitchen.Activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
                                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Below id my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashriskitchen"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java/com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashrikitchen.Fragments', 'src/main/java/Fragements']
        }
    }
}

android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.socialize:facebook:3.1.6'
    compile 'com.socialize:ioc:3.1.6'
    compile 'com.socialize:loopy:3.1.7'
    compile 'com.socialize:library:3.1.7'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev176-1.22.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

This Problem occurs only when I add the below file in the gradle.. Else the app runs without crash.

```
    compile 'com.socialize:facebook:3.1.6'
    compile 'com.socialize:ioc:3.1.6'
    compile 'com.socialize:loopy:3.1.7'
    compile 'com.socialize:library:3.1.7'
```

Comment: Try to add Under my /libs folder I had an old android-support-v13.jar that got compiled with gradle. Your app tried to use the ContextCompat class of this .jar and the class didn't have the static getDrawable(Context) method. Removing this .jar solved problem.

Comment: In libs folder I dont have any jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade your **`gms:play-services`** version .

**Don't**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

**Do**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
```