# How to remove android-support-v13.jar older version in android studio

Tags: android

[image: This is my new issues screen shot][This is my project structure screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGkRB.png). Am having a error which I already posted here '[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getDrawable(Landroid/content/Context;I)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497458/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-getdrawablelandroid-content-conte)'. Unfortunately I haven't received any support. After some research to overcome this problem I need to remove older version of 'android-support-v13.jar'. Under my libs folder no jar files are there. I also searched in my local appdata(C:\Users\sivabala\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support). Now my question is what are the other possible path that 'android-support-v13.jar' may be present.

Comment: goto `FILE->PROJECT STRUCTURE ` check lib

Comment: Can u please elaborate.. where will be lib in FILE->PROJECT STRUCTURE

Comment: Android studio . From Left Top

Comment: use google play version `10.2.1/11.0.0` instead of `8.4.0`

Comment: Thanks mate. That solved me the previous issue 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497458/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-getdrawablelandroid-content-conte'. Thanks a ton @Intellij Amiya

Comment: Glad to hear .What about this problem ??

Comment: Having another problem.

Comment: Elaborate please .

Comment: its a warning .

Comment: However am having this problem.  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method addOnPageChangeListener(Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewPager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewPager' appears in /data/app/com.jeyashri.kitchen.jeyashriskitchen-2/base.apk:classes45.dex)

Comment: add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'`

Comment: No this is not helping. Also tried com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha1'