# Android - Alert Dialog builder not working - Fatal Exception

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I keep getting an exception when I want to display an alertdialog when edit button is clicked. When i comment out alertDialog.show(), the app works, otherwise, it crashes. Please let me know where the error is. I really would appreciate an explanation.

Exception is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.kiran.expensecalculator, PID: 3325
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/support/v4/view/OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompatLollipop; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatLollipop' appears in /data/data/com.example.kiran.expensecalculator/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.1_1f99a106c741de69d4ed910ed0109f9cc344ee12-classes.dex)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$LollipopViewCompatImpl.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(ViewCompat.java:1558)
                      at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(ViewCompat.java:2829)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:425)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:80)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:214)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:256)
                      at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
                      at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
                      at com.example.kiran.expensecalculator.Income.editIncomeValues(Income.java:256)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My xml code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_income"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.example.kiran.expensecalculator.Income">

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/save"
            android:id="@+id/btnSave"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="insertIncomeValues"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/edit"
            android:onClick="editIncomeValues"></ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnDel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/del"></ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

My Activity code where edtEdit onClick not working is:

```
public class Income extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView edtTextMonth , edtTextTitle, edtTextDate, edtTextIncome;
    TableLayout tableLayoutDisplay;
    ImageButton btnNext, btnPrev, btnEdit;
    DBHelper myDB;
    int monthNumber = 12, year = 1964;
    String monthName, prevNext;
    String T1, T2, T3; // selected row values
    int activity = 0, tr; // '0' as an IncomeActivity in DBHelper insertData method.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_income);

        myDB = new DBHelper(this);
        edtTextMonth = (TextView) findViewById(txtViewMonth);
        edtTextDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDate);
        edtTextTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
        edtTextIncome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIncome);
        btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        btnPrev = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrev);
        btnEdit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);

    }
public void editIncomeValues(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Income.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Edit");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure, You wanted to make decision");
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                edtTextTitle.setText(T1);
                                edtTextDate.setText(T2);
                                edtTextDate.setText(T3);
                                edtTextTitle.requestFocus();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: There seems to be a link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049107/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-setonapplywindowinsetslistener) to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create `AlertDialog` just delete this line:

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

and change the last line to :

```
alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

Comment: Hi Omid thanks for the reply, But the result is same, my application is still crashing

Comment: @CodeLearner I've already tested your code. it works. whitch support design package do you use?

Comment: import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;       
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

Answer (score 0):

I see that on click "editIncomeValues()" is called where you are showing of dialog.

I guess you are facing issue because you have set actions for Alert Dialog - **alertDialogBuilder** and performed show on a new dialog - **alertDialog** .

Your code is perfect. Just change dont create another alertDialog(alertDialog) and use the same one created(alertDialogBuilder) for showing as well...

Goodluck..! Hope it helps :)