# Fatal exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isDeviceProtectedStorage

Tags: android, cordova

When using [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase), I ran in to the following error:

```
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX, PID: 6859
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method isDeviceProtectedStorage(Landroid/content/Context;)Z in class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/com.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX-1/base.apk)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1751)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1726)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5855)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5447)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5386)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
04-27 16:59:35.745  6859  6859 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-27 16:59:35.749   975  1021 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXX/.MainActivity
04-27 16:59:35.779  2358  6582 I PBSessionCacheImpl: Deleted sessionId[10372086956677829] from persistence.
04-27 16:59:35.795  2358  2358 W SearchService: Abort, client detached.
04-27 16:59:35.798  2358  2358 E WorkerRegistryImpl: getWorker() is called after WorkerRegistry disposal.
04-27 16:59:35.798  2358  2358 E WorkerRegistryImpl: getWorker() is called after WorkerRegistry disposal.
```

At first I thought it is because [isDeviceProtectedStorage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#isDeviceProtectedStorage(android.content.Context)) in android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat was only added in API 24 and later. But even when using a newer device with Android 7, the same messages appears.

Why is the method not found? Is it because I failed to install some library?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049107/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-setonapplywindowinsetslistener

Comment: My gradle file has `compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"`

Answer (score -1):

As per Android developer documentation isDeviceProtectedStorage was added in 24.0.0. If you are running the app below this mentioned API version, make a check for it

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24){
    //TODO: Do your stuff here.
}
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#isDeviceProtectedStorage(android.content.Context)