# No static method combineMeasuredStates(II) When implementing a Bottom Navigation View

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a `Bottom Navigation View` but everytime I run the project logcat gives this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method combineMeasuredStates(II)I in class Landroid/support/v7/widget/ViewUtils; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.ViewUtils' appears in /data/app/lungu.aubry.quick-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes28.dex)
              at android.support.design.internal.BaselineLayout.onMeasure(BaselineLayout.java:69)   
              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17624)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5552)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17624)
              at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView.onMeasure(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:143)
              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17624)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5552)
              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17624)
              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5552)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
```

My top level gradle file is as follows:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile 'com.satsuware.lib:usefulviews:2.3.6'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
compile 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.7'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.7'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

The application itself is not giving me any problems

Comment: I faced a similar problem due to conflict in library versions, see answer here it might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39104669/724913

Answer (score 0):

Add your build.gradel code for more assistance, we can not help you with only the log but with all your code.

However i think that the builds tools version and SDK version must be same 
like (25.X.X)

you can take more about on: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method combineMeasuredStates(II)I in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032724/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-combinemeasuredstatesiii-in-clas)