# Bottom Naviagtion not working?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I am working with bottom navigation I have the below code in my xml to get bottom nagvigation, but when I run the app I keep on getting this below exception.

Here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.activatic.paychek.HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#f1f1f1">

    </FrameLayout>


    <!--<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>-->
   <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />

   <!-- <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the exception that I am facing.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method combineMeasuredStates(II)I in class Landroid/support/v7/widget/ViewUtils; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.ViewUtils' appears in /data/app/com.activatic.paychek-2/base.apk:classes5.dex)
    at android.support.design.internal.BaselineLayout.onMeasure(BaselineLayout.java:69)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
    at android.support.design.internal.BottomNavigationMenuView.onMeasure(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:143)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:689)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Below is my build.gradle file please find and let me know this are all dependecies I am using.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':ccp')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11+'
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11+'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'

    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.4'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: can you show your add your gradle file

Comment: yep let me update my question

Comment: test case : have you added design dependence?

Comment: yep I have added

Comment: please post your app's build.gradle

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/a/48032771/8089770

Comment: @SunilP Make sure your design library is as the same version of appcompat library

Comment: @VishvaDave yep I tried still facing the same issue

Comment: @SunilP after changing dependencies clean rebuild and restart the studio then run

Comment: still same issue, even after clean and rebuild

Comment: @SunilP share your **`build.gradle`** with question

Comment: @VishvaDave I have added build.gradle to my question

Comment: @SunilP make most of the dependencies to same version like support v4, recyclerview, v7, design and all of that as all are having different versions right now :(

Comment: yep finally I solved it with the help of this link given by @VishvaDave
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032724/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-combinemeasuredstatesiii-in-clas/48032771#48032771

Comment: @SunilP Please mark my answer as correct if it solved your issue

Comment: the link which you commented I have voted for that

Answer (score -2):

**Please refer below link for your problem**

[Android new Bottom Navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar)

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

with the help of this link, you can check what you doing in your code. what is an exact issue. so you have to compare your code to this one and check what you doing mistake

Comment: Do not post link only answer