# AppCompatActivity is not working properly

Tags: android, android-studio, appcompatactivity

[image]I am developing an app which uses AppCompatActivity. I have been struggling since so many days solving this error but no luck and no reply for such an answer on StackOverflow. The gradle is built successfully without any error. But when the app is installed in the device, I get a force close error.

I am attaching my Android Monitor(logcat) content here. Please help me with this.

> ```
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/support/v4/view/OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;)V
> at
> android.support.design.internal.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.<init>(ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java:61)
> at
> android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:99)
> at
> android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:95)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
>  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>  at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at
> org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
> at
> org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
> at
> org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
> at
> android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
> at
> android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
> at
> android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
> at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
> at
>  android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
> ```

here is my gradle file attached. Please have a look at it.

Comment: may be this post will be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049107/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-no-static-method-setonapplywindowinsetslistener

Comment: Try updating your gradle dependancies to higher versions check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034938/no-static-method-setonapplywindowinsetslistener-exception-in-android

Comment: It was version 24.2.1 but showing this error. Then I had to downgrade everything to 23.4.0 and the problem is same. Don't know what to do.

Comment: can you send me your source code so let me import it and check @RiddhiWala

Comment: @PratikDasa and sJy Please find my gradle file in the question itself. I have attached it. I was not able to copy paste the code.

Comment: Try to exclude your support-v4 module

Comment: do you fixed this ??

Comment: Add this line in gradle and check it:     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
 @RiddhiWala

Comment: ok let me check all the solutions.

Comment: @Piyush you are a Life Saver! Thank you so much. I wasted 2 days after this uselessly.. I am so much relaxed now. Thank you once again. :)

Comment: @RiddhiWala Np ! You'r wel come !!

Answer (score 2):

The answer to my question was given by @Piyush. The two dependencies were clashing I guess. so in short the answer to my issue will be if you are using

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.+'
```

etc.

then ***DO NOT USE***

```
compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
```

along with it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your app compat gradle as like below

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

don't use gradle with +

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
```

Hope this helps..!!